# Python 3 TypeError: string indices must be integers Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm facing with below error when i'm trying to convert json file to csv.

Could you please help me for understanding and fixing this error ?

> reportdata = report_parsed['data']
>   TypeError: string indices must be integers

```
   .
   .
   .
  with open('report.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(response, outfile)

    infile = open('report.json', 'r')
    outfile = open('report.csv', 'w')

    report_parsed = json.loads(infile.read())
    reportdata = report_parsed['data']

    csvwriter = csv.writer(outfile)
    count = 0

    for item in reportdata:
        if count == 0:
            header = item.keys()
            csvwriter.writerow(header)
            count += 1
        csvwriter.writerow(item.values())

    outfile.close()
```

**Sample Json**
https://gist.github.com/gokturkenez/0117172b69a30f7be4cc18b3f7a7db7f

Comment: Whatever the value of `data` is in `report_parsed` is not an `int`.

Comment: The error message seems clear enough: `report_parsed` is a string and `'data'` isn't an integer, hence not a valid index. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Have you verified what is in `report_parsed`?  Python seems to think it is a string.

Comment: Looking at your sample link, `data` is a `list` containing another `dict`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`report_parsed` is a `string` not a `JSON` object, Just add another `json.loads` to your code:

```
report_parsed = json.loads(json.loads(infile.read()))
```

Comment: It's worked ! Now i'm facing with issue when i'm trying to write them in to the csv file but it's easy to fix. Thanks a lot !